# Gridview Population

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been looking at this code all weekend.  I know there is data and I can pull it through other queries but the GridView will not show and populate.  Suggestions?

```
        string sqlSelection =
                    "SELECT * FROM [COMPANY].[dbo].[parking] ";

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DATACONNECTION"].ToString());
        //This connection works in MSSMS and in other pages I have on the same server

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelection, cn);

        SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);

        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(dTable);
            //debug shows: dTable <not set>


        GrdDynamic.Visible = true;
        GrdDynamic.DataSource = dTable;
        GrdDynamic.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and checked to see how many rows exist in dTable after the fill?  If there *are* rows, it might help us to see the aspx code for the GridView as well.

Comment: At the risk of being ridiculed, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and use the quick-watch-window. Here are more details: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: what's your DB name? "Company"? because select statement has table reference listed as "[COMPANY].[dbo].[parking]". Best solution is to remove DB name like "select * from [dbo].[parking]"

Comment: Tim, that was extremely helpful, thank you.  I see now that the dTable is empty and therefore not able to fill data in the line sda.Fill(dTable)

Comment: @Geekender - I hope (but can't guarantee) that nobody would ridicule you for not knowing how to do something.  We all started out not knowing what we do now, and we're all still learning.  That's what the site is for, and you are asking good questions in good faith, and attempting to provide the info you think we need.  I for one appreciate the fact that you're putting effort into it!

Comment: Does the GridView have the AutoGenerateColumns ="false" ???  If so, remove it and it should show up.

Comment: @Zachary The issue is that the query is pulling back nothing, not that the gridview isn't showing it properly.

Comment: Is it possible the connection string is wrong?  Perhaps pointed to a test database instead of live, where there is no data?

Comment: Yes I did have AutoGenerateColumns = false, but removed that and it still does not show.  @Servy I double checked my query using MSSMS and the query works there.  stepping through now to see where it is failing.

Comment: @Geekender when you debug the code are you able to see whether there are rows in the dTable.

Comment: @prashantht I get dTable <not set> is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Geekender in watch window can you get dTable.Rows.Count. Place a break point in line GrdDynamic.Visible = true;

Comment: Also this line of code SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda); is not needed (this won't make any difference)

Comment: @prashantht I set the breakpoint and see a windows when I debug but am not sutre how to get the value for dTable.Rows.Count.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10976/discussion-between-prashanth-t-and-geekender)

Comment: User error....found the problem.  The code was all good except it was under a submit button and not page load.  I needed to check the simple stuff first.  Thanks a ton for putting me to school on debugging though.  This will be EXTREMELY helpful.

Comment: Please, show GrdDynamic properties, maybe you didn't bound anything field and disable their auto creation.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this behavior when the account in the connection string doesn't have rights to the database because the account the web service doesn't have access to the account. If you are using a machine account (not a sql login) try to create a sql login (if possible) and assign it to the db. Or you can temporarily using the anonymous account to use the login you are using for the management studio (more than likely yourself).  I have also had this happen when the web server could not see the SQL server due to routing issues. You can test the last one by going to the server and trying to ping the sql server. The worst one situation is when a firewall has stopped the port from connecting. I am not sure of a sure fire test for this situation because it depends a lot of how your network is configured.